# Eigenvalues of rectangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have a non-zero real $n$ by $m$ matrix $M$, then there may exist a non-zero unit vector $v$ of $m$ elements so that $Mv = 0$.  I understand we can't call this an eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$.

> Why is this not a sensible definition of an eigenvector of a rectangular matrix?

If $m > n$ then $M$ must have rank less than $m$.

> Can such a matrix still have no  non-zero unit vectors $v$ of $m$
>   elements so that $Mv = 0$?

Note that the $0$ term on the right hand side is $n$-dimensional and $v$ is $m$-dimensional.

Comment: More columns than rows guarantees existence of a non-zero vector in the nullspace.

Comment: Eigenvalue $\lambda$ means $Mv=\lambda v$. This can't happen if $M$ isn't square.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you this answers the first question.

Comment: My first comment answers the 2nd question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh thank you. Can you explain briefly why this is and is it even true if we restrict ourselves to unit-vectors?

Comment: If $Mv=0$ then $M(17v)=0$, where $17$ is a variable. Take the value of $17$ that makes $17v$ a unit vector. As to why there is one, have you not come across the fact that a system of homogeneous linear equations with more unknowns than equations is guaranteed to have a non-zero solution? It goes by considering the (reduced) row-echelon form of the matrix.

Comment: @GerryMyerson OK thank you I did know that it turns out. I need to revise my question (ask a different one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. An eigenvector of a matrix $A$ is such a vector $v$ that $Av = \lambda v$. In the case when the eigenvalue is $\lambda = 0$, this means that you want a vector where $Av=0\cdot v$. The problem when $A$ is rectangular is that if $A$ has $n$ rows and $m\neq n$ columns, the vector $Av$ has $n$ components while the vector $v$ has $m$ components. This means that although $Av=0$ and $0\cdot v = 0$, these two zeroes are not the same. One is an element of $\mathbb F^n$, the other of $\mathbb F^m$.
2. Sure, just set $M$ to be an all-zero matrix, and you will have plenty of vectors for which $Mv=0$.

Comment: Thank you. So I am interested in matrices where $Mv = 0^n$ for some non-zero real $v$.  Do they exist when $M$ is non-square, non-zero and real?

Comment: @felix:  Sure.  Take any $n\times n$ matrix with determinant zero and append any vectors you want to pad it out to $n$ by $m$.  The nullspace will be at least as big as the original matrix's was.

Comment: Sorry I meant the opposite. Do there exist non-square, non-zero $M$ with $m>n$ such that there is no non-zero vector with $Mv =0$. The answer is no in any case.

Comment: Of course they do. Take the matrix $[-1,1]$ for example. It has $m=2>1=n$ and has a null vector of $[1,1]^T$.

Comment: I think you are missing the word "no" in "no non-zero".

Comment: I was answering the question posed in the first comment, sorry. For the second comment, the answer is no. This is because the dimension of the image of $A$ plus the dimension of the kernel of $A$ equals $n$, the number of rows of $A$. Since the image of $A$ is a subspace in a $m$ dimensional space, it can have at most $m$ dimensions, so if the dimension of the kernel, $n$ minus (at most $m$), must be greater than $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first, such a $v$ would be in the nullspace.  It is a vector sent to zero by $M$.

An eigenvector would satisfy $Mv = \lambda v$, but this is impossible since on the left $v$ is $m$-dimensional and on the right it is $n$-dimensional.

The study of the analogue of eigenvalues for non-square matrices is the study of the singular value decomposition, or "SVD".  See [the English Wikipedia article on SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).

Comment: OK so I am asking about non-zero real vectors in the null-space of a rectangular matrix it seems. I see what you mean about $Mv = \lambda v$ having different dimensions. I am not clear if you answered my second question though (even though the 0 on the right has a different dimension to $v$).